# spark-submit a python class in the site-packages directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have all of my custom python packages installed in the site-packages directory on my spark cluster, so that they are accessible to the pyspark interpreter. Does spark-submit allow submitting a python class name rather than the full path to the python file?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
spark-submit /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/etl/etl.py
```

But I'd rather not have to know the location of the package. Is there a way to do something like

```
spark-submit --python-class etl.Etl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to give an absolute path to the file, or else you create a driver.py file that imports the required class and executes.

You should probably do python -m <your_module> instead, there's no concept of main class in Python so you'll have to point to the file which implements `if name == "__main__":` top-level code.

Create an on-the-file driver.py file that imports your class and passes it to spark-submit if spark-submit is required (for example submitting in cluster mode).

However, you'll have to make sure in all the scenarios that your python package is installed on all spark nodes, else the executors will start failing your tasks